# php - Ответ на GET запрос

Tags: php

Только - только начинаю разбираться в php. Допустим, мне надо передать на скрипт параметр:

```
http://site.ru/test.php?p=1
```

А скрипт должен вернуть клиенту строку `hello". Как это сделать? Примерно представляю такой код:

```
<?php
int a = webLink.getParam(p);
if(a == 1) return "hello";
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` первое `var_dump` делает дамп переменной любого типа, а вот `$_GET` суперглобальный массив с запросом.

Comment: Рекомендую сначала узнать принципы работы PHP, сервера, как они взаимодействуют, куда попадают параметры от сервера и пр.

Comment: Запрос простой: "проверка существования параметра get php".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == '1'){
echo 'Hello';
}
```

Comment: Если есть параметр p и если он равен  единице то отвечаем hellо верно?

Comment: Надеюсь модератор изложит свою жалобу?

Comment: да Сергей, если есть параметр и он он равен 1 ....

Comment: Как же понять чей ответ лучше? Люди, люди, ещё такой вопрос, пока клиент не может ничего отправить так как Сайт ещё не на хостинге. Для тестинга юзаю дейвер. А вот как проверить что он работает? В браузере ссылку пишу с параметром а где поймать ответ? Или это только с клиентом можно проверить?

Comment: да Сергей, все верно.

Comment: думаю, настройка Денвера (полагаю его вы имели введу) это совсем другая история

Comment: Да, Денвер. Ладно, разберусь, спасибо

Comment: @СергейГрушин кто первый ответел, тот лучше